# copy many files with big sizes over rsync

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, scp

I have database server on AWS and the backup of databases are over 1000 files with sizes can reach 5GB,

I am using a script to copy the backup to my data center using rsync, but the copy is slow, I have 200MB internet, download speed of files using wget can reach  17MB/s, but using rsync start with 5MB and the decrease to 700K,

what is the best solution to copy these files with high speed and secure connection

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Just copy the binlogs and load them locally.

Better yet replicate to a local instance.

Comment: and what do you do in case of a corruption? how does a replica does protect you from this?moreover in my mind is, that he does not tell which kind of database has been used. so a ssh tar copy could also speed up

Comment: What type of corruption? Simultaneous corruption on the local replica and the remote? Corruption of the binlogs in transit? How does a ssh tar copy fare better?

Comment: I mean I had already a database corruption, sofar only a backup from the past safes my a.. ;) well the tar copy has the speed on the side and afterwards can also be a rsNc be runned. but in fact there is no option that we can come to the person due product suggestions are off topic